# Does actionscript version matters when making ad flash banners for any media company?

Tags: flash, actionscript, banner

sometimes, the spec sheet from the media company won't state actionscript version.
so I guess it should be save to use as2 rather than as3.
but is that actually actionscript version will affect the flash player.

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript version in itself shouldn't matter, unless your contract states that you need to hand over source code and their internal developers only work with a specific version.

Mostly, you're just targeting a specific flash player version to ensure the widest range of people can see your ad. Most people should be fine with FP10: http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same question. I'am setting up a workflow for creating banners. I found out that the version does matter. Since most banners are distributed by advertising systems which work with "clickTag". In short the advertising system provides the URL for the flash banner.

Unfortunately the safest moment right now is to use AS2 and export for flash player 9 or lower.